# Replacing multiple occurences of abbreviations in a string

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I need to replace multiple abbreviations in a string.

Result should be:

```
One DUMMY_0 two DUMMY_0 three DUMMY_0 four profession
```

What am I doing wrong?

```js
const abbr = ['vs.', 'p.o.'];
let str = 'One vs. two vs. three vs. four profession';

abbr.forEach((ab, index) => {
  const regex = new RegExp('\b' + ab + '\b', 'g');
  str = str.replace(regex, 'DUMMY_' + index);
});
console.log(str);
```

Comment: What is happening that you don't want?

Comment: Start by removing the \b: `const regex = new RegExp(ab, 'g');`

Comment: @mplungjan even I tried the same first but `p.o.` makes it as `/p.o./g` which will fail. Currently I have added `.replace()` for dot. Guess there must be a better way for it

Comment: The question got answered while I wrote my answer. You need to escape regex special chars

Comment: @BjørnØyvindHalvorsen No, `0`is correct, as it is the `0`th element of the `abbr` array

Comment: I got it... removed my comment to late i guess.. sorry. I put out an alternative way of doing it, since, as you can see with Rajesh's answer, Regex quickly gets a bit out of hand...

Comment: @BjørnØyvindHalvorsen I just over-engineered it to handle extra cases. My original answer was very similar to `nagyf`'s answer, but thought of other cases that might come handy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have to remove `\b` in your regex (why did you write that there?), second: you have to escape the dots in your regexes, because dot means "any character" in a regular expression.

The modified code:

```js
const abbr = ['vs.', 'p.o.'];
    let str = 'One vs. two vs. three vs. four profession';
    
    abbr.forEach((ab, index) => {
      const regex = new RegExp(ab.replace(/\./, "\\."), 'g');
      str = str.replace(regex, 'DUMMY_' + index);
    });
    console.log(str);
```

**Edit:** Added escaping in the loop

Comment: As the abbr array has hundreds of elements, would it be possible to escape them programmatically in the loop?

Comment: Sure, see the answer of @Rajesh. You have to use`new RegExp(ab.replace(/\./, "\\."), 'g');`

Answer (score 2):

Remove `'\b'` from regex.

Also you will have to escape special characters.

```js
const abbr = ['vs.', 'p.o.'];
let str = 'One vs. two vs. three vs. four profession';

abbr.forEach(function(ab, index) {
  var regex = new RegExp(getParsedString(ab), 'g');
  str = str.replace(regex, ('DUMMY_' + index));
});
console.log(str);

function getParsedString(str) {
  var specialChars = /(?:\.|\!|@|\#|\$|\%|\^|\&|\*|\(|\)|\_|\+|\-|\=)/g;
  return str.replace(specialChars, function(v) {
    return "\\" + v;
  })
}
```

#### Edit 1

- Added a generic parser to handle special characters other than `.`.
- Replaced `const` with `var` inside loop. If using ES6 then `let` is preferred.
- Removed arrow function as context binding is not required

Comment: Thorough answer.. i like it :)

Answer (score 2):

An alternative way of solving this issue, with less code and without regex.

```js
const abbr = ['vs.', 'p.o.'];
let str = 'One vs. two vs. three vs. four profession';

abbr.forEach((ab, index) => {
  str = str.split(ab).join('DUMMY_' + index);
});
console.log(str);
```